# UILocalNotification display alert on notification center when app is in foreground

Tags: ios, iphone, uilocalnotification

I am working with UILocalNotification to notify users about their schedule. Everything is working fine but I'd like to know whether there is a way to display notification alert on notification center when the app is in foreground.

The alert will not be fire on running application main view.

Please help me.

Comment: Please help me is it possible to show notification on notification center if application is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in didReceiveRemoteNotification Method.

```
UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) 
{
    NSString *cancelTitle = @"OK";
    NSString *message = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"] valueForKey:@"alert"];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                        message:message
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertView show];

} else 
{
    //Do stuff that you would do if the application was not active
}
```